# How do I get information about shared Circles on Google Plus?

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I'm using the Google Plus API for a project that I'm working on. I'm hoping to be able to get information about shared circles in which a particular user has been included.

I've seen this active on Circle Count. For example, half way down Guy Kawasaki's profile page (http://www.circlecount.com/p/+GuyKawasaki), you can see the number of circles in which he has been shared. It also includes information about each circle like the date it was shared, the number of users that were included in it and a few more details.

I'm using PHP and am hoping to do this through the API, but I don't see any options for this type of information in the API. When I use the API to get information about activities, I don't see any field that seems to identify a shared circle post as anything different from any other post.

If you know a way to workaround the lack of support for this in the API through some form of a hack, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking over here: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/getting-started

> ```
> Read the names of a user's circles and the membership of each circle
>
> Google+ API v1        NO
> Google+ Domains API   YES
> ```

So I get on this url (Google+ Domains API): https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/#Circles

Where the information about circles can be retreived. With this call:

```
/people/{userId}/circles
```

Comment: I'll dig into that and report back and if correct, I'll definitely accept your answer. I have a feeling that you just made my 3 day long headache go away. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this API allows you to pull information about the circles of the app's authenticated user but not information about publicly shared circles which reference/include the app's authenticated user.

Comment: What about this: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation Domain wide authentication instead of user specified authentication.